# Write characters like $ or € to unicode form while writing data with XMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml, unicode, xmlstreamwriter

i am using an XMLStreamWriter object to write some data into an xml file. 
My problem is that when i encounter a special character like $ or €, it remains as it is. Is it possible to write this kind of characters in their unicode form ? as an example ; writing \u0024 instead of $ and writing \u20ac instead of €.
I am using the encoding "UTF-8" and when JBoss is used, i am using the "com.bea.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactoryBase" as the "javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory".

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Any Unicode character can be represented in UTF-8. No strange tricks are necessary for characters such as $ or €.

Comment: Agreed. You only need to escape characters that have special meanings in XML, like `<`,`>`,`"`, etc...

Comment: What makes `$` or `€` "special" to you? Without knowing which characters you need to treat as "special", there's no way to give an answer.

Comment: Have you tried writing "$£€" into your XML file and reading it back?  If it works, then you have no problem.  If it does not work, then the way it fails will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Also, writing things like `\u0024` or `\u20ac` is not the standard way to escape characters in XML. It should be `&#x0024;` or `&#x20AC;` instead.

Comment: I am aware that these are not special characters for xml standard. Anyway i've found a way to transform it before actually writing it with xml file.

Comment: But you haven't told us what does make them special to your use. Are those the only special characters, or is there a whole class of special characters, and so on. The best approach depends heavily upon that.

Comment: As others say, as scary as it looks, the best thing is to just keep those characters as is. If it's not broken, don't fix it. In the best case it will still work (but you didn't really achieve anything), worst case your app will break if any language other than English is used.